# MySql партицирование

Tags: mysql, partition

Имеется таблица на 22+ ляма строк из которой необходимо строить отчеты, данные хранятся за пол года. С оптимизацией выборки больших данных почти не сталкивался. Почитав несколько топиков про оптимизацию, наткнулся на партицирование, кто подскажет на сколько эффективным будет партицирование по месяцам? Прошу посоветовать варианты оптимизации для работы с большими данными.

Comment: Все очень сильно зависит от ваших "отчетов". Если вы строите отчеты затрагивая данные сразу за несколько месяцев - выйгрыш будет не существенный, а если отчет пройдет по смежным "месяцам" затронув всего пару дней из каждого "месяца" - возможно даже проиграете в скорости.

Comment: Данные могут строиться и по текущему месяцу а так же за несколько сразу, в зависимости какой диапазон будет выбран

Comment: Чтобы было понятнее, это таблица входящих звонков, и необходимо предоставить статистику

Comment: Индексирование я как понимаю эффекта особого не даст

Comment: Тогда, если оптимизация уже требуется, идете по неверному пути... 
1) Очередь отчетов.
2) Готовый отчет сохраняется(при повторном запросе такого же отчета - выгружается уже готовый).
3) Верно выставленные индексы.
4) Что то что еще мог не вспомнить на ходу.

Comment: Индексирование полей по которым идет выборка(даты\номера телефонов,  иные поля участвующие в условиях фильтрации) - это самое первое что нужно делать.
ps. Зачастую важен порядок установки фильтрации, т.е. `where id<10 and date>10.10.10` даст лучший результат нежели `where date>10.10.10 and id<10 `(но тут индивидуально это приведено как пример о чем идет речь).

Comment: Спасибо будем пробвовать